# Why my interstitial ads is not showing in andorid kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, ads, interstitial

**I tried it lots of times but I failed. I am new to Android development. Is my code correct? Please help me. I created a class for load the ads loading work : **

```
class InterstitialAds {


    var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null


     fun interAds(context: Context){

        MobileAds.initialize(context)


        var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

        InterstitialAd.load(context,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                adError?.toString()?.let { Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, it) }
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd

            }
        })
    }
}
```

**
In Adapter :
**

```
holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener {


            val interstitialAds = InterstitialAds()
            interstitialAds.interAds(context)


            if (interstitialAds.mInterstitialAd != null) {
                interstitialAds.mInterstitialAd!!.show(context as Activity)
                interstitialAds.mInterstitialAd!!.fullScreenContentCallback =
                    object : FullScreenContentCallback() {

                        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is dismissed.
                            interstitialAds.mInterstitialAd = null
                            interstitialAds.interAds(context)
                            progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            webView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                            thumnail.visibility = View.GONE

                            val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
                            webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true


                            webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
    
                                    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                                    fullButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE

                                }
                            }

                            webView.loadData(item.videoEmbed!!, "text/html", "utf-8")


                        }

                    }
                
            }
```

**Can anyone help me to solve this issue.  Is my code correct? Please help me. I created a class for load the ads loading work **

Comment: What error/ result you are getting?

Comment: not showing any error only ads is not showing

Comment: Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("455FDC94B1F5B4415BD853EEB4FFCDB0")) to get test ads on this device. showing it

Comment: how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in **production**, Use `RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("455FDC94B1F5B4415BD853EEB4FFCDB0"))`

before `MobileAds.initialize(context)`

If you do not know TestDeviceId then search **safeDK Device ID** in logcat.

If that does not work then change your package name for testing purposes. And change it back before releasing a new update